# Search video through Facebook Open Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I know we can search for public objects such as post, event, checkin in Open Graph API using:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY&type=OBJECT_TYPE
However I can not search for video objects.
Is there a way to search for videos in facebook using their title or description?

Answer (score 3):

You can search videos using some attributes via FQL: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video.

Unfortunately, the title and description are not among those...

Comment: it allowed me to retrieve videos from user and his friends, however I also want to search for every public videos available on facebook. is that possible?